# How to prevent Bower from hanging up when installing angular-ui-tree?

Tags: bower, angular-ui-tree

I've been trying to install angular-ui-tree using bower version 1.8.0, but it keeps hanging up on me.

I've tried the following commands:

- `bower install angular-ui-tree`
- `bower install angular-ui-tree --save`
- `bower install angular-ui-tree --save --verbose`
- `bower install angular-ui-tree --verbose`

Verbose doesn't print a stack trace, however all commands above print the info of already installed packages.

I've also tried using `bower init` or restoring previous versions of bower.json, but to no avail.

The original bower.json file:

```
{
  "name": "meten",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "*",
    "bootstrap": "*",
    "angular-animate": "*",
    "angular-bootstrap": "*",
    "angular-cookies": "*",
    "angular-resource": "*",
    "angular-route": "*",
    "angular-sanitize": "*",
    "angular-smart-table": "*",
    "angular-touch": "*",
    "angular-strap": "*",
    "angular-nvd3": "*",
    "papaparse": "*",
    "components-font-awesome": "^4.7.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "*"
  },
  "appPath": "app",
  "moduleName": "metenApp",
  "overrides": {
    "bootstrap": {
      "main": [
        "less/bootstrap.less",
        "dist/css/bootstrap.css",
        "dist/js/bootstrap.js"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

What can I do to fix bower?

Comment: What Node & Bower versions are you using?

Comment: Solution found in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36679810/bower-install-display-prompt-input-message-debian